# Can you convert a System.Windows.Control.Image to a System.Drawing.Icon?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

The title of the question pretty much states the problem.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified an example from [here](http://khason.net/blog/how-to-use-imagesource-no-handler-in-winforms-as-systemdrawingbitmap-hbitmap/).  This seems to work pretty good.

```
    public static Icon Convert(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = null;
        var width = bitmapImage.PixelWidth;
        var height = bitmapImage.PixelHeight;
        var stride = width * ((bitmapImage.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);

        var bits = new byte[height * stride];

        bitmapImage.CopyPixels(bits, stride, 0);

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* pB = bits)
            {
                var ptr = new IntPtr(pB);

                bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, stride,
                                                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb,
                                                ptr);
            }

        }

        return Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer helped me a lot. But I found a problem where my image when I assign it to a picturebox and then resize the box. My solution was to draw the image back into a new bitmap so I no longer need the unsafe array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635968/open-and-display-a-hd-photo-in-winforms-application/5646307#5646307

Comment: This leaks the Hicon handle.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, I've used the hints found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f9919df8-0658-40ce-84ac-a81244c980de):

```
public static Icon Convert(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(); // With this we also respect transparency.
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
    encoder.Save(ms);

    var bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
    return Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon());
}
```

Comment: This leaks the Hicon handle.

Answer (score 2):

We had this problem a couple of months back and we found this solution

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1684.htm

I'm sooo glad that we insert references in our comments to where we found something. I prefer sending this to you instead of my code because it's merge with a get multiple zipped file which complexify what you really want to get at.

Comment: This converts a System.Drawing.Image to a System.Drawing.Icon.  I'm trying to convert a System.Windows.Control.Image to an System.Drawing.Icon.

Answer (score 0):

I made from your code a WPF XAML IValueConverter Class that converts a byte()  array with an image to an Icon , here is the code :

```
Public Class ByteArrayToIconConverter
Implements IValueConverter

' Define the Convert method to change a byte[] to icon.
Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, _
    ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, _
    ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object _
    Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert

    If Not value Is Nothing Then
        ' value is the data from the source object.
        Dim data() As Byte = CType(value, Byte())
        Dim ms1 As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(data)
        Dim ms2 As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()

        Dim img As New BitmapImage()

        img.BeginInit()
        img.StreamSource = ms1
        img.EndInit()

        Dim encoder As New PngBitmapEncoder()  
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(img))
        encoder.Save(ms2)

        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(ms2)
        Dim newIcon As Icon = Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon())

        Return newIcon

    End If


End Function

' ConvertBack is not implemented for a OneWay binding.
Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, _
    ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, _
    ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object _
    Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack

    Throw New NotImplementedException

End Function
End Class
```