# Open and display a HD Photo in WinForms application

Tags: .net, winforms, image

I'm writing a small program where I would like to handle a number of different image types - among other things: "HD Photo" aka "JPEG XR".

I've tried a simple `Image.FromFile()` but I get an `OutOfMemoryException`. I've tried to search for some solutions but the precious few results I've found gave me the suspicion that this might only work in a WPF application. Is this true? If not then how can I open such a file so I can put it in a `Picturebox`?

Comment: I'm investigating a possible workaround of hosting a WPF control in my Winforms app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an acceptable workaround. I've written a small WPF Controls Library that loads HD Photos and returns a System.Drawing.Bitmap.

It's a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569561/dynamic-loading-of-images-in-wpf) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337199/can-you-convert-a-system-windows-control-image-to-a-system-drawing-icon) question with a bit of my own improvements thrown in. When I tried the original source I had the problem that the image vanished when I resized the picturebox. It probably has something to do with just pointing to some array for the image info. By drawing the image into a second safe Bitmap I managed to get rid of that effect.

```
public class HdPhotoLoader
{
    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapFromUri(String uri)
    {
        return BitmapFromUri(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapFromUri(Uri uri)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
        src.BeginInit();
        src.UriSource = uri;
        src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        src.EndInit();
        img.Source = src;

        return BitmapSourceToBitmap(src);
    }

    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapSourceToBitmap(BitmapSource srs)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap temp = null;
        System.Drawing.Bitmap result;
        System.Drawing.Graphics g;
        int width = srs.PixelWidth;
        int height = srs.PixelHeight;
        int stride = width * ((srs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);

        byte[] bits = new byte[height * stride];

        srs.CopyPixels(bits, stride, 0);

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* pB = bits)
            {

                IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(pB);

                temp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(
                      width,
                      height,
                      stride,
                      System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb,
                      ptr);
            }

        }

        // Copy the image back into a safe structure
        result = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);
        g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(result);

        g.DrawImage(temp, 0, 0);
        g.Dispose();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad you found your solution.